# Windows 10 Home - Login screen is now asking for password instead of 4 digit pin

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, authentication, windows-live

My primary desktop is running Windows 10 Home.  Normally when I boot the computer up, I am presented with the login screen where I am asked to enter a 4 digit pin in order to login to windows.   Last night, I was getting warnings telling me that my Intel Optane drive was almost full, and during the process of moving some data off of that drive, I realized that I did not have the Intel Optane software interface installed on my machine.

So, I went to intel's website and downloaded and installed the application.   When the install was complete, I received a warning from the installer telling me I needed to reboot in order to launch the application.   I did attempt to launch the app without rebooting, but windows would not load the intel optane software without a reboot.   I restarted my desktop, and when windows boots I am no longer being asked to enter a 4 digit pin.   The interface shows my full first and last name and is asking for a regular password instead of a pin.  The problem with this is, I never set a password on my account - only a PIN.

I looked up the issue online and found one possible solution that involves holding down the right-hand shift key while rebooting the machine from the windows login screen.   Doing this boots the computer into a troubleshooting menu.  From the troubleshooting window I select Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt.   When I select Command Prompt, my computer reboots and then loads a screen telling me that the windows login that I used to set up the computer was my work email address, and I will need to enter my windows live password in order to launch the command prompt.   I am asked to select the administrative user account (which is my full first and last name) and then I am asked for my password.

Using another computer, I go to https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-us to login to my windows ID.   I am able to get logged into Microsoft with my work email address and password.   After logging in to my account using my work email, I can even see my desktop listed under managed devices (note the D: Optane drive and how full it is).

[image]

So I have now confirmed that my work email account is somehow attached to this computer, and I for sure know my Windows ID password because I am able to get logged in and view the desktop I am having this problem on.

However, when I try to authenticate (which I am required to do in order to proceed), I get a message telling me my password is incorrect.   Just to be sure, I have reset my windows ID password twice for my work email.   No matter what I change the password to I am able to login to my windows ID account (which confirms that I know what the current password is), but I am still unable to authenticate to open the command prompt on my desktop.    I noticed that the screen where I enter my password seems to be telling me I am entering the wrong password did not appear to be actually checking the credentials on the internet, so I disconnected the ethernet (this desktop does not have WiFi) cable and booted into the troubleshooting interface for windows 10.   The windows troubleshooting interface does not appear to be trying to authenticate over the internet at all, because when I authenticate to try and open the command prompt with the Ethernet cable removed I get the same error.  I would think that if my computer was attempting to authenticate with Microsoft's servers - I would get some sort of a message saying that the computer does not have an internet connection.   This leads me to believe no matter what I reset my windows ID password to that I will not be able to open any of the troubleshooting tools in Windows 10 since I am being asked to authenticate in order to open any of the available tools.

Is there some way to recover from this?   I am not sure why installing the Intel Optane application changed my computer from using a 4 digit pin to requesting the password for my Windows ID but not accepting it - but if there is any way to get windows to switch back to asking for a PIN instead of asking me for a password, or even log in to windows at all I would be happy.

Does anyone know of any offline editors I could use to add another admin account to my Windows 10 Home desktop?

[image]

Comment: Try all your old passwords first. One method is to rename osk.exe (on screen keyboard) to cmd.exe careful when doing this as not to overwrite it, change to osk.old then rename cmd to osk, then osk to cmd. Reboot machine, on the login screen open the on screen keyboard, this should give you a cmd with administrator rights. From there add your new admin user, reboot and login as this admin, change cmd and osk back to original.

Comment: I know that used to work in Windows 7, but how do I go about renaming the executable if I cant login to windows at all in the first place?

Comment: Try getting a bootable Windows ISO. That'll give you a cmd at X:/. Cd to C: and drive on

Comment: good idea, ill try that and get back to you.

Comment: “Does anyone know of any offline editors I could use to add another admin account to my Windows 10 Home desktop?” - Just use the built-in Administrator account after you enable it.  See my answer on the subject for assistance with in that matter

Comment: Do you have any other Microsoft accounts that you may have linked to your PC? I know you said your work account is linked, and that you tried your work account's password, but perhaps you have a personal account that you set the PC up with?

Comment: @aa2397 Alright so I was able to replace the on screen keyboard with the command prompt.  What do I do next to reset my password?

Comment: Hey I got it.  Here is a link to the fix I used https://operating-systems.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-admin-user-account-using-cmd-prompt-windows-0125689/